# Query on SQL Server stored procedure takes longer for specific data than for all data

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a query in a stored procedure that is retrieving data from several tables of my SQL Server database. From my application I call this stored procedure with some parameters to filter the data.

The strange thing is that, for all data returned for "X" week of year (about 2600 records) it takes about 30 seconds to retrieve the data. But if I add a specific "center" filter for the same week of year (about 1800 records), it takes about 3 minutes to get the data!

If I run just the query, it works well (30 seconds for all data and about 22 seconds for filtered data). The issue is when I run the query through the stored procedure!

How is this possible? Why does filtered data is taking about x6 times than getting all data? Why am I missing? Am I writing the stored procedure correctly? How can I do this in a more efficient way?

My stored procedure code is something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE EventMonitoring
    @EventType AS CHAR(1),
    @Year AS INT,
    @Week AS INT,
    @CenterID AS CHAR(2),
    @AreaID AS INT
AS
    DECLARE @SQLCommand AS VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @MessageError AS VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQLCommand = ' SELECT ....
                   ....
                   ....
                   ....
                   FROM   Event E
                   INNER JOIN ...
                   INNER JOIN ...
                   INNER JOIN ... 
                   WHERE E.EventYear = ' + CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR) +  
                   ' And E.EventWeek = ' + CAST(@Week AS VARCHAR) +
                   ' And E.EventType = ' + CAST(@EventType AS VARCHAR) 

    IF @Centro <> '-' --If application sends - as the parameter, it gets all centers
    BEGIN
        @SQLCommand = @SQLCommand + ' AND E.CenterID = ''' + @CenterID + '''' 
    END

    IF @Area <> 0 --If application sends 0 as the parameter, it gets all  areas
    BEGIN
        @SQLCommand = @SQLCommand + ' AND E.AreaID = ' + CAST(@AreaID AS VARCHAR) 
    END

    SET @SQLCommand = @SQLCommand + 'GROUP BY ....'

    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC(@SQLCommand)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ....
    END CATCH
```

Comment: Can you show the table structure, and indexes on it? How many rows in the table?

Comment: what happens when you run your query outside of the proc using `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`? Does the execution time more closely mirror your SP execution times?

Comment: Show us both plans? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: It's came from a ADO connection?

Comment: ok, I'll try to show you the tables, but as I said, it's a lot of tables, anyway, if it's something on indexes or table structure issues, why does the query itself works ok and why it takes longer when i put the query on the SP? And yes, it comes from ADO but, anyway, if I run the SP directly, same happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter how this shakes out, I bet this can be solved by adding an additional column (`CenterId`) to an index.

When the difference comes down to 'when I add an additional column to the where clause, the query takes a whole lot longer', that indicates that the additional column is not covered by the index the query is able to use without that clause.

To fix that, find the existing index that query uses without the additional clause and add the additional column to the `include()` of that index, or make a new index (seems wasteful to make a whole new index to add one more `int` column though).

Find the index that is being used for `Event` with the fast query, and see if it includes `CenterId`. If you do not know how to find it, you basically need to check the execution plans. If you still can not find it, you can share your execution plans and we will help you find it. Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

I can only guess (vaguely) what the index is going to look like without knowing more about how `Event` joins to the rest of your query, but the index might look something like this, only missing `CenterId`:

```
create nonclustered index ix_Event_cover 
  on dbo.Event(EventYear,EventWeek,EventType)
    include (CenterId, AreaID, [JoinColumns], [SelectedColumns])
```

Comment: Ok, I'll give this a try, but, why when I run the query itself it works well? the issue came up just when I run the exact same query through the SP using a string query

Comment: @GustavoAlvarado That would be something you would check/paste the execution plans to find out. There are some obscure possibilities, but it isn't worth delving into them until you put forward the effort to include execution plans for your question.

Comment: Thanks @SqlZim, when generating the query plan I realized there was a missing index that solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I faced a situation like this at my work and we solve just adding the `SET ARITHABORT ON` parameter inside the proc because the ADO connections.

**EDIT**

When a procedure generates the script in runtime sql engine don't see the real parameters to build a good plan for the query. It's call **Parameter Sniffing**. So try something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE EventMonitoring
    @EventType AS CHAR(1),
    @Year AS INT,
    @Week AS INT,
    @CenterID AS CHAR(2),
    @AreaID AS INT
AS   
    DECLARE @MessageError AS VARCHAR(MAX)

    BEGIN TRY

    IF @Centro <> '-' --If application sends - as the parameter, it gets all centers
    BEGIN
        SELECT ....
                   ....
                   ....
                   ....
                   FROM   Event E
                   INNER JOIN ...
                   INNER JOIN ...
                   INNER JOIN ... 
                   WHERE E.EventYear = @Year 
                    And E.EventWeek = @Week  
                   And E.EventType =EventType  AND E.CenterID = @CenterID 
                   GROUP BY ....
    END

    IF @Area <> 0 --If application sends 0 as the parameter, it gets all  areas
    BEGIN

        SELECT ....
                   ....
                   ....
                   ....
                   FROM   Event E
                   INNER JOIN ...
                   INNER JOIN ...
                   INNER JOIN ... 
                   WHERE E.EventYear = @Year 
                    And E.EventWeek = @Week  
                   And E.EventType =EventType  AND E.AreaID = @AreaID 
                   GROUP BY ....
    END





    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ....
    END CATCH
```

**Another try**

After a quickly read in the article pointed by SqlZim try this last one shot with  `ARITHABORT ON` and `option(recompile)`

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE EventMonitoring
        @EventType AS CHAR(1),
        @Year AS INT,
        @Week AS INT,
        @CenterID AS CHAR(2),
        @AreaID AS INT
    AS
SET ARITHABORT ON
        DECLARE @SQLCommand AS VARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @MessageError AS VARCHAR(MAX)

        SET @SQLCommand = ' SELECT ....
                       ....
                       ....
                       ....
                       FROM   Event E
                       INNER JOIN ...
                       INNER JOIN ...
                       INNER JOIN ... 
                       WHERE E.EventYear = ' + CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR) +  
                       ' And E.EventWeek = ' + CAST(@Week AS VARCHAR) +
                       ' And E.EventType = ' + CAST(@EventType AS VARCHAR) 

        IF @Centro <> '-' --If application sends - as the parameter, it gets all centers
        BEGIN
            @SQLCommand = @SQLCommand + ' AND E.CenterID = ''' + @CenterID + '''' 
        END

        IF @Area <> 0 --If application sends 0 as the parameter, it gets all  areas
        BEGIN
            @SQLCommand = @SQLCommand + ' AND E.AreaID = ' + CAST(@AreaID AS VARCHAR) 
        END

        SET @SQLCommand = @SQLCommand + 'GROUP BY .... OPTION (RECOMPILE)'

        BEGIN TRY
            EXEC(@SQLCommand)
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ....
        END CATCH
```

Comment: I'm using ADO too, but, in my case, if I run the SP directly, same happens, not just when I call the SP from ADO

Comment: In this case I strong recommend to convert the String query in real query.

Comment: That is not quite right. The existing procedure will generate a new execution plan for each execution, your version will be subject to parameter sniffing and related issues. [Parameter Sniffing, Embedding, and the RECOMPILE Options - Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options)

Comment: I also tried that, with "if" satements I validate if the parameters were set to "all" or a specific value to run real queries, and the issue is the same! that's why I don't know what else to do

Comment: Thanks for your examples Krismorte, but I added SET ARITHABORT ON and OPTION (RECOMPILE) and still the same issue...

Comment: Ok, just one thing. In SSMS press the CRTL+L print the screen and add this image at the questio for all to see the query plan.

Comment: Ok, no problem, for the SP (with string query) or the actual query?

Comment: @GustavoAlvarado for the SP

Comment: Thanks @Krismorte, when generating te query plan as mentioned above, turns to be a missing index that solved the issue.

Comment: @GustavoAlvarado awesome!